# systemctl не запускает python скрипт, если он работает с файлом

Tags: python, linux, debian, daemon

Подскажите из-за чего может возникать следующая ситуация?

Если в .py файле есть ссылка, то просмотр статуса через команду *systemctl status myparser.service* выдаёт такую ошибку:
***systemctl service fails with: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE***
Если этим же файлом(/usr/bin/python3) запускать питоновский, то всё работает как надо.
т.е. проблемы в логике .py файла не вижу
конфигурация /etc/systemd/system/myparser.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Myparser
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /root/first/study_pr/study_pars.py
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Питоновского:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time

def send_telegram(text: str):
    token = "ТОКЕН_ТЕЛЕГОБОТА"
    url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot"
    channel_id = "КАНАЛ_ДЛЯ_БОТА"
    url += token
    method = url + "/sendMessage"

    r = requests.post(method, data={
         "chat_id": channel_id,
         "text": text
          })

    if r.status_code != 200:
        print(r.status_code)
        raise Exception("post_text error")



#article_list_link = open('article_list_link.txt', 'r+')

all_list = []
#for line in article_list_link:
#    all_list.append(line)

#article_list_link.close()
URL_TEMPLATE = "ССЫЛКА_ДЛЯ_ПАРСИНГА"
while True:
    #article_list_link = open('article_list_link.txt', 'r+')

    r = requests.get(URL_TEMPLATE)

    soup = bs(r.text, "html.parser")
    article_list = soup.find_all('h1', class_="post-title")
    for name in article_list:
        link = name.a['href']
        if link not in all_list:
            text_ar = name.text + name.a['href']
            send_telegram(text_ar)
            #article_list_link.write(link)
            all_list.append(link)
        else:
            time.sleep(120)
        time.sleep(60)
    #article_list_link.close()
```

Изначально было желание, чтобы уже просмотренные парсером статьи, падали в текстовый файл.
Чтобы при перезапуске парсера, не дублировать повторно новости.
Но заставить работать демона через systemctl  удалось только закоментировав файлы.
Подскажите в чём может быть причина?

Сервер на Debian 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WorkingDirectory=` в юните укажи или используй полные пути к файлам

Comment: Помогло, спасибо большое)